# I want to run a small kiln off a living room circuit with ext cord out to the yard.

Tags: electrical

I want to run a small kiln. The specs say 115V, 15A, Amp fuse size 20, wire 12, plug type 5-20P. Can I plug into a regular household circuit?

Comment: How long is the extension cord?  What gauge are the wires in the cord?

Answer (score 1):

No, the 5-20P configuration will only fit circuits designed for and equipped with a 20 amp receptacle:

[image]

[image]

Comment: The kiln has a standard plug so I'm guessing the previous owner switched it but I don't think the temperature is getting high enough and I wondered if that could be caused by it plugging into a 15A circuit/receptacle.

Comment: I don't think the 15 amp circuit would be causing your temp. problem. If the device were trying to pull more than the circuit could deliver you would likely blow a fuse or trip a breaker.

Comment: Are you using an ext cord? What gauge? How long?  If it's not getting hot enough I would suspect either voltage drop or one of multiple heating elements burned out.  Although the amount of heat being produced being plugged in is no more than a hair dryer. To produce the high temp like kilns do the kiln would have to build up heat over time and keep it all inside.